# Sending data to a specific Kafka paritions using AWS DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-dms, aws-msk

As per the question,
Is it possible to configure
an AWS DMS instance to one specific parition of an aws kafka

TABLE 1 -> DMS 1 -> Kafka_Topic(parition 0)

TABLE 2 -> DMS 2 -> Kafka_Topic(parition 1)

just asking a question

Answer (score 0):

Since the minimum number of partitions for a single topic in Kafka is 1 (Though not advisable). You can configure a DMS instance to migrate a single table from a source database to MSK.

```bash
<path-to-your-kafka-installation>/bin/kafka-topics.sh \
   --bootstrap-server $BS --command-config client.properties \
   --create --topic table-1-topic --partitions 1
```

Comment: Hi, can you point out the specific section as I went through the documentation and they don't guarantee it anywhere. Neither is there any parameter for manually giving a partition id

Comment: @eeeVillain Just create topics with a single partition.

Comment: that could be a way around, but the question still stands if dms allows to select a specific partition to send data

Comment: @eeeVillain, sure! Looking forward to the answer that feels more native!